# how to execute some code after execution of another class method code?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a common web services class. in that class I have written method getcitydetail(). I want to populate that city detail after getting the result.

I have written following code in `viewDidload`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   let objWebService = NTMWebServices()
    objWebService.getCityDetail()
}
```

After execution of getcitydetail, I want to do some operation here.
I think we can do it using closure in swift. but I didn't get an idea how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a closure in this situation try something like

```
func getCityDetail (completion:()->()){

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {

        //background thread, do ws related stuff, the ws should block until finished here

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            completion() //main thread, handle completion
        }
    }
}
```

then you can use it like

```
objWebService.getCityDetail {
   //do something when the ws is complete
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of these:

1. If  `getCityDetail()` is asynchronous request then, [Use Delegate to
   respond with the result to the registered class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557688/synchronous-url-request-on-swift-2). 
       Ex:

   ```
   NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error:
   ```

   NSError!) -> Void in

   ```
       // Handle incoming data like you would in synchronous request
       var reply = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
       // Conform to the protocol with the results here
   })
   ```
2. [iOS Swift Pass Closure as Property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196938/ios-swift-pass-closure-as-property) - As here u can use the closure as property and can communicate between the classes