# ios swift property block setting and getting

Tags: swift, swift3, ios10, ios10.3.2

in objective-c we do

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) void(^Name)(id input, id selectedListItem);
```

then we set property

```
if (self.Name) {
    self.Name(self,nil);
}
```

for accessing it viewcontroller

```
[classObject setName:^(id input, id selectedListItem)
// do something with the input and selectedListItem
];
```

how we can do it in swift3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196938/ios-swift-pass-closure-as-property ?

Comment: You have the setting and accessing reversed.

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) void(^Name)(id input, id selectedListItem);
```

is

```
var name: ((input: Any, selectedListItem: Any?) -> ())? = nil
```

Setting is

```
obj.name = { (input, selectedListItem) in
    // do something with the input and selectedListItem
}
```

Calling is

```
if let name = obj.name {
     name(self, nil)
}
```